# TypeError: 'ModelBase' object is not iterable

Tags: python-3.x, django

Necesito exportar un reporte a excel desde mi aplicación django, generé el código pero al momento de probar descargar el archivo me arroja el mensaje "TypeError: 'ModelBase' object is not iterable", revise mi modelo y no logro encontrar cual seria mi problema.

```html
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

# Create your models here.

class equipo(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    marca = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    modelo = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    serie = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    rotulo = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    fecha_ing= models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    tipo = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    activo = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    descripcion = models.CharField(max_length=600)

class asignacion(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    usuario_asig = models.CharField(max_length=350)
    cargo = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    departamento = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    fecha_entrega = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    marca_equipo_asig = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    modelo_equipo_asig = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    serie_equipo_asig = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    rotulo_equipo_asig = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    tipo_equipo = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    activo = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class telefono(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    marca_tel = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    modelo_tel = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    serie_tel = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    numero_tel = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    fecha_ing_tel = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    usuario_asig_tel = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    departamento_usuario = models.CharField(max_length=250)

class pda(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    ot = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    modelo_pda = models.CharField(max_length=350)
    serie_pda = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    fecha_ing = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    fecha_desp = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    serie_bateria = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    num_inventario = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    sucursal = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    region = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    estado = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    dias_st = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    descripcion_pda = models.CharField(max_length=250)

class usuario(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length= 50)
    apellido = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    cargo = models.CharField(max_length= 50)
    email = models.CharField(max_length = 30, null = True, blank = True)    
    clave = models.CharField(max_length = 30, null = True, blank = True)
```

la miración que generé despues de este modelo es la siguiente

```html
from django.db import migrations, models
import django.utils.timezone


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    dependencies = [
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='asignacion',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, serialize=False)),
                ('usuario_asig', models.CharField(max_length=350)),
                ('cargo', models.CharField(max_length=150)),
                ('departamento', models.CharField(max_length=300)),
                ('fecha_entrega', models.DateTimeField(default=django.utils.timezone.now)),
                ('marca_equipo_asig', models.CharField(max_length=200)),
                ('modelo_equipo_asig', models.CharField(max_length=200)),
                ('serie_equipo_asig', models.CharField(max_length=250)),
                ('rotulo_equipo_asig', models.IntegerField(default=0)),
                ('tipo_equipo', models.CharField(max_length=100)),
                ('activo', models.BooleanField(default=False)),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='equipo',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, serialize=False)),
                ('marca', models.CharField(max_length=200)),
                ('modelo', models.CharField(max_length=200)),
                ('serie', models.CharField(max_length=250)),
                ('rotulo', models.IntegerField(default=0)),
                ('fecha_ing', models.DateTimeField(default=django.utils.timezone.now)),
                ('tipo', models.CharField(max_length=100)),
                ('activo', models.BooleanField(default=False)),
                ('descripcion', models.CharField(max_length=600)),
            ],
           
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='pda',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, serialize=False)),
                ('ot', models.CharField(max_length=200)),
                ('modelo_pda', models.CharField(max_length=350)),
                ('serie_pda', models.CharField(max_length=250)),
                ('fecha_ing', models.DateTimeField(default=django.utils.timezone.now)),
                ('fecha_desp', models.DateTimeField(default=django.utils.timezone.now)),
                ('serie_bateria', models.CharField(max_length=250)),
                ('num_inventario', models.CharField(max_length=250)),
                ('sucursal', models.CharField(max_length=200)),
                ('region', models.CharField(max_length=250)),
                ('estado', models.CharField(max_length=100)),
                ('dias_st', models.IntegerField(default=0)),
                ('descripcion_pda', models.CharField(max_length=250)),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='telefono',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, serialize=False)),
                ('marca_tel', models.CharField(max_length=200)),
                ('modelo_tel', models.CharField(max_length=200)),
                ('serie_tel', models.CharField(max_length=250)),
                ('numero_tel', models.IntegerField(default=0)),
                ('fecha_ing_tel', models.DateTimeField(default=django.utils.timezone.now)),
                ('usuario_asig_tel', models.CharField(max_length=200)),
                ('departamento_usuario', models.CharField(max_length=250)),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='usuario',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, serialize=False)),
                ('nombre', models.CharField(max_length=50)),
                ('apellido', models.CharField(max_length=50)),
                ('cargo', models.CharField(max_length=50)),
                ('email', models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=30, null=True)),
                ('clave', models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=30, null=True)),
            ],
        ),
    ]
```

la vista que genere para poder exportar mi tabla con datos a un excel quedo mas o menos asi

```html
class ReporteEquipoExcel(TemplateView):
    def get(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        equipos = equipo.objects.all()
        wb = Workbook()
        ws = wb.active
        ws['B1'] = 'REPORTE DE EQUIPOS'

        ws.merge_cells('B1:E1')
        ws['B3'] = 'Marca'
        ws['C3'] = 'Modelo'
        ws['D3'] = 'Serie'
        ws['E3'] = 'Rotulo'
        ws['F3'] = 'Fecha ingreso'
        ws['G3'] = 'Tipo'
        ws['H3'] = 'Descripcion'

        cont = 7
        for equipos in equipo:
            ws.cell(row = cont, column = 2).value = equipo.marca
            ws.cell(row = cont, column = 3).value = equipo.modelo
            ws.cell(row = cont, column = 4).value = equipo.serie
            ws.cell(row = cont, column = 5).value = equipo.rotulo
            ws.cell(row = cont, column = 6).value = equipo.fecha_ing
            ws.cell(row = cont, column = 7).value = equipo.tipo
            ws.cell(row = cont, column = 8).value = equipo.descripcion
            cont+=1

        nombre_archivo = "ReporteEquipoExcel.xlsx"
        response = HttpResponse(content_type = "application/ms-excel")
        content = "attachment; filename = {0}".format(nombre_archivo)
        response['Content-Disposition'] = content
        wb.save(response)
        return response
```

Comment: Tu error es sencillo, está en la línea: `for equipos in equipo:` si te das cuenta `equipo` es el nombre del modelo, por eso el error te dice `'ModelBase' object is not iterable` porque no es iterable, además, otro error gramatical o `typo` es que estás usando en el `for` la variable `equipos` para representar un item de un iterable, pero tendrías un error también, intenta renombrar algo así: `for _equipo in equipos:` y luego dentro del `for` actualiza todas las llamadas a `equipo` (que es tu modelo) por `_equipo`

Comment: lo pase por alto completamente! tu aclaración fue de mucha ayuda se agradece el aporte.